# Binding a Custom Resource to a Node

Tags: kubernetes, binding, nodes, scheduling, kubernetes-custom-resources

I am creating a custom scheduler in kubernetes to schedule custom resources. This scheduler should find a suitable node for a custom resource and binds custom resource to that node. I created the logic for finding a suitable node but how can I now bind this node to custom resource using kubernetes API?

I tried to google it but could not find any solution.